# svn on commit, web.config UN-checked by default - is there a way to do this?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**Business case**: our team has an environmentOverride setting key in web.config, used for debugging purposes, and sometimes a team member will accidentally commit their web.config in with an incorrect override value, like "production" when we want it to be "beta".

**Desired outcome**: I right click on my project folder, click "SVN Commit..." and have the default value of the checkbox next to "web.config" UN-checked?  Right now it always checks each file by default.  Maybe a property called "LeaveUnCheckedWhenTryingToCommit"=true, or something like that, would be awesome to do on individual files, like web.config.

Chances are we won't be making many changes to web.config anyways, so this would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

----UPDATE----

Site that shows how to implement the solution, http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html) are what you want.

It will automatically uncheck it for you if you add the file to the special *ignore-on-commit* changelist, it will make it pretty damn obvious that the 'temporary' change is not to be included in the commit even if you add it to an arbitrary changelist. [Tortoise has good support for this feature](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.5_releasenotes.html#changelist-support).

Comment: gbjbaanb, this is great! how do you actually add the web.config to the changelist called "ignore-on-commit" ?  right-click on the file in win7 file explorer -> TortoiseSVN -> "Add to changelist..." ?  Thanks!

Comment: jk, found it: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html

Answer (score 0):

Would [ignoring the file](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html) work?

Comment: good thought, but, I think that would make web.config disappear from the Commit list altogether, where instead I want it to still show up, but just have an un-checked checkbox next to it.

Comment: Ah - in that case, ignoring isn't what you're looking for. I'm afraid I don't know how you'd get it unchecked by default :(